# C#: What does the [string] indexer of Dictionary return?

Tags: c#, dictionary

What does the `[string]` indexer of `Dictionary` return when the key doesn't exist in the Dictionary?  I am new to C# and I can't seem to find a reference as good as the Javadocs.

Do I get `null`, or do I get an exception?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: That would have been a good thing to try I suppose.

Comment: What is a string operator anyway?  The dictionary can have any type as a Key.

Comment: i meant the [] operator, with a string as an argument

Comment: Ah ok thats what in .NET we refer to as the indexer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you mean the indexer of a `Dictionary<string,SomeType>`, then you should see an exception (`KeyNotFoundException`). If you don't want it to error:

```
SomeType value;
if(dict.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
   // key existed; value is set
} else {
   // key not found; value is default(SomeType)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an example of how to use the out thingy...ha.

Comment: The TryGetValue and TryParse examples are probably the most common "out" use-cases you'll see in most day-to-day code.

Comment: When I was reading about them I couldn't really see a great use.  It just seems like a two return value hack.

Answer (score 14):

As ever, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) is the way to find out.

Under Exceptions:

```
KeyNotFoundException
The property is retrieved and key does not exist in the collection
```

(I'm assuming you mean `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, by the way.)

Note that this is different from the [non-generic Hashtable behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item.aspx).

To try to get a key's value when you don't know whether or not it exists, use [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, The .net documentation is still kinda hard for me to wade through and find the info I need.

Comment: It's mostly pretty good (particularly the offline version, IMO - use the Index) but you need to know that to find the indexer documentation you usually look for the Item property.

Comment: Index...ok, I will remember this.  I prefer dict.get(key) from Java.  Oh well...I'm kind of a fan-boy.

Comment: Item, not Index. As for preferring the Java way - give it time. C# is a *much* nicer language than Java IMO. It takes a while to adjust, especially with the various new features of C# 3.0, but it's lovely :)

Comment: You can use either Google (http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=system.collections.generic.dictionary+site%3Amsdn.microsoft.com) or MSDN (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?query=system.collections.generic.dictionary&ac=8) to search the MSDN documentation.

Comment: I've been working in C# for 7 years and didn't find it either. Didn't know it was referred to as Item. I seem to remember indexers used to just be explicitly listed on the class or members page. Thanks for pointing that out in your follow up @JonSkeet

Comment: The question specifically mentions Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, but it might be worth noting that the IDictionary<TKey, TValue> documentation for the item property does not mention the KeyNotFoundException exception, and only specifies NotSupportedException when setting the value corresponding to a key which does not exist (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.item(v=vs.100).aspx).  The Dictionary<> generic class implements the IDictionary<> interface, but luckily LINQ returns an instance of the class from ToDictionary().

Comment: @Greg: You've linked to the documentation for the non-generic interface. The [generic `IDictionary<,>` indexer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyxt2e2h(v=vs.110).aspx) *does* talk about `KeyNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try a

```
dict.ContainsKey(someKey)
```

to check if the Dictionary contains the key or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to using `TryGetValue`, you can first check if the key exists using `dict.ContainsKey(key)` thus eliminating the need to declare a value prior to finding out if you'll actually need it.